# Android Studio - Empty report when running local unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing

Im running local unit tests (located under src/test/java) either by clicking the verification/test gradle project or from the command line "./gradlew test --continue". When the execution completes with failed tests i get the following message:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':MyProject:testDebug'.
>     There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/asaf.k/AndroidStudioBranch/MyProject/build/reports/tests/debug/index.html

But when i examine the html file it is always empty
[image]

Why ?